# Conflict between nath package and align?

Tags: incompatibility, nath

I juste began to use the very user-frieldly nath package, which seems to work quite perfectly up to those lines :

```
\begin{align*}
U^{old}(q, \sigma_S) & = \{\pi^{\otimes m_k(\pi^S)} \in A(B^\star) \tq c(\pi^S)=q, \pi_S\simeq\sigma_S\} \\
N^{old}(q, \sigma_S) & := \# U^{old}(q, \sigma_S) = \sum_{\pi \in A(B^\star) \tq \pi_S\simeq\sigma_S} dim \ (\pi^S)^{K_0^S(q)}  = \sum_{d \div q} \tau(q/d) N(d, \sigma_S)
\end{align*}
```

This environment breaks the compilation and return the errors :

```
! Use of \math@cr@@ doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...ved@d = #1\def \reserved@a {#2}
\def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.142 \end{align*}

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 142.
```

Is it an incompatibility between nath package and the align environment ? Il seems to me that some align work in my TeX, hence it should be an unprotected macro that is the seed of the problem. But I tried to eliminate every personal one...

Any help will be welcome !

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Working Example....

Comment: Q: Is [there] an incompatibility between [the] `nath` package and the [`amsmath` package]? A: Yes.

Comment: `texdoc nath` the nath manual says `(math mode commands must be those of Nath).` in other words use of amsmath environments is explicitly not supported. Most people would resolve the incompatibility by using amsmath, which makes your math markup far more compatible with the majority of latex classes.